# calling a method from outside of class (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods

Here is my exemple :
https://codesandbox.io/s/test-uz-713xy
As you can see in this rather nice example,
I try to assign 2 differents methods to 2 differents buttons ("skyfall" and "vileMurder").

But these methods are calling from outside of my class, they are therefore not correctly recognized and I got the following error message : `skyFall is not defined`
or `vileMurder is not defined`

is anyone know how to fix that for me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those function are indeed not defined in the scope you are calling them.
This can be fixed in two steps:

#### 1. Pass the functions as props from the Profils component

```
              <IsHeStillAlive
                skyFall={this.skyFall}
                vileMurder={this.vileMurder}
                panel={panel}
```

And change the mapping function to take a lambda instead of `function` because functions bring their own this variable bound to the function context.

```js
this.state.data.map((panel) => {
```

#### 2. Use the props from `IsHeStillAlive`

```
 <Button onClick={() => props.vileMurder()}>
 ...
 <Button onClick={() => props.skyFall()}>
```

The changes above will be enough to have the functions recognised and executed but there are other errors down the line, also related to the context of `this`. I recommend that you read [the MDN doc about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

You could also be interested to convert your components to [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). Although it is not mandatory, this is now the recommended way to define components and it prevents most of the context binding issues to happen.

Comment: thanks mate, looks like the good solution. 
I have another issue with the update of the informations so if you know why thanks to help me again.